# Creating an EBS Volume from snapshot, resizing it via terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I've opened this issue on the [hashicorp/terraform-aws-provider repository wherein you can't maintain disks via terraform that were created from an AMI instance](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/22047). Now, I realized there's another underlying problem that I need to figure out (but maybe someone from stackoverflow already knows/figured out)

So, like I said in the issue I raised, if you have the following code, it will create the resource *disk* from the snapshot_id provided. It will follow the same size as the snapshot...

```
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "disk" {
   availability_zone = "ap-southeast-2a"
   type              = gp3
   snapshot_id       = same.snapshot.id.associated.with.instance
}
```

Now if that weeks later (like in my case) I need to double the disk size of *disk*, I added the `size` argument, and gave a value of 128 (snapshot was originally 64), after I run plan, terraform doesn't see it as a change. What's the best way to deal with this?

```
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "disk" {
    availability_zone = "ap-southeast-2a"
    type              = gp3
    snapshot_id       = same.snapshot.id.associated.with.instance
    size              = 64
    }
```

I'm thinking of just creating a new disk, attaching it to my EC2 instance, then copying all the files from the disk with snapshot, then changing the mountpoint to this new disk... but maybe, there's an elegant way I'm not seeing or I don't know yet?

Comment: You should be able to try setting the `snapshot_id` argument value to `null` temporarily and observing the provider behavior afterward. It should no longer attempt to back with a snapshot and resize the disk if the logic is well done.

Comment: Wouldn't this destroy the volume?